# jQuery fadeOut callback to fadeIn not working

Tags: jquery, fadein, jquery-callback

I'm trying to fadeOut a div and then fadeIn the next div once the first one has gone (to stop the next div from coming below the first div and then bouncing up once the previous one goes). I searched for answers and using a callback function was what people suggested. However I'm using the following code, and it fades out the first div, but doesn't fadeIn the next one. Any ideas?

```
$(function() {
     $('.qc-answerA').toggle(
       function(event) {
         $(this).find('input').attr('checked', true);
         $(this).addClass("qc-answerSelected");
         $('.qc-answerB').removeClass("qc-answerSelected");
         $('.qc-answerC').removeClass("qc-answerSelected");
         $('.qc-answerD').removeClass("qc-answerSelected");
         $('.qc-answerE').removeClass("qc-answerSelected");
        //This is the fadeIn fadeOut function 
         $(this).parent('div').fadeOut("fast", function(){
            $(this).parent('div').next('div').fadeIn("fast");
        });
       },
       function(event) {
         $(this).find('input').attr('checked', false);
         $(this).removeClass("qc-answerSelected");
       }
     );
});
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Watch out for your `parent()` usage with `this`. `this` is something else inside the callback than it is inside the toggle function.

Comment: I think Jakub is right - did you try changing the fadeIn() line to `$('someId').fadeIn("fast");`, just to see whether that's the line of code that's not working for you?